# Fb.ui apprequest returning null response

Tags: fbjs

After sending an Facebook app request in FB.ui using Javascript SDK, the response returned in the callback function is 'null', if the user sends the request or not. I have tested with multiple Facebook accounts and receive the app requests, however.

```
    , sendRequest: function() {
  parent.FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    to: this.game.attributes.opponentFbId,
    title: 'My App',
    message: 'I sent you a challenge on My App',
  }, function (response) {
                console.log(response)
        });
```

According to http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui, method 'apprequests' should return an array of request_ids (via response.request_ids), or response.to .However 'response' returns null when I try to log it in console

I have tried something similar with method 'feed' in FB.ui and can read the response (and response.post_id), however not with 'apprequests'.